# secure a bare web service using API manager and ESB

Tags: api, wso2, esb

all. I have an scenario when using WSO2 products. I don't know if it is a good way, so post it here. 
I may have a web service deploy in AS, and it is bare without security, then this service is published to API manager. the question is whenever someone get logged in, he can invoke the API. so is it possible to first deploy the web service to ESB first, and using the security policy to secure the service, then publish to API manager(with JWT enabled). so when an api is invoked, the JWT will tell ESB who is invoking the service, and according to the policy, ESB will decide if the end user is authorized to the service.

if is possible, can someone give an sample to learn?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this post useful.

http://ssagara.blogspot.com/2013/07/wso2-esb-set-ws-security-ut-user-names.html

It explains a scenario where each user has a different password to access a secured backend service and the password for the user looked up using a Password Callback Handler. JWT token is used to find which user is invoking the API.